# What is this small (~1" x 2") rectangular hole in my basement?

Tags: basement, foundation, drainage, hole

We have some vinyl tile flooring in our basement and the section that contains the washer/dryer had one of the tiles develop a hole due to some kind of depression underneath.  I took the time to cut away the broken vinyl tile to reveal a rectangular hole.

I expected some kind of depression, but this hole is ~32cm (12in) deep and clearly not an accident given the rectangular shape.  I suspect it might have originally fed into a french drain system around the foundation of the house but I can't tell if there is a 90° bend at the bottom or if there is something plugging it down there.

Since I thought this was just a depression, I was going to fill it with a cement repair product.  Should I instead try and cover this with some kind of tiny grate to prevent objects from falling in?  If yes, any recommendations for where to get such a beast?

Some more context: House built around 1978/1979 in south central PA

[image: proportional to my foot]
[image: depth is about 32cm]
[image: rough edges]
[image: as deep as it my phone camera will go]

Comment: 32 inches deep...is that the thickness of the foundation?  It does look like a marking stake would fit in it.  You can buy (maybe rent?) a snaky type camera thing that would help you inspect it.

Comment: See edits -- typed inches by reflex but I meant cm

Answer (score 1):

With it being an odd shape and small size, same as a 1x2, which it probably was at one time.  Would just fill it in.

Would use sand for about 3/4 to the top and pack the sand down.

Add small, about 1/2 inch gravel to about four inches to the top, packed also.

Fill the last three or four inches with cement, probably a small box of hydraulic fast setting, or any kind you can get in a small amount.

Try to level it, best you can to the cement floor.